# SequelizeJS - How to Map Nested (eager loading) Models for Raw Queries?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Below is an example of a raw query.

```
  const query = `SELECT 
    links.name, links.type, links.code, links.originalUrl,
    domains.id as 'domain.id', domains.host as 'domain.host',

    count(
      CASE WHEN hits.datetime > "${past}" AND hits.datetime <= "${now}" = true then 1 END
    ) as hitCount 

    FROM links

    LEFT JOIN hits ON links.id = hits.linkId
    LEFT JOIN domains ON links.domainId = domains.id
  
    WHERE links.userId = ${req.user.id}
  
    GROUP BY links.id, hits.linkId

    ORDER BY hitCount DESC
  
    LIMIT 5`;

  const links = await sequelize.query(query.trim(), { 
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    model: Link,
    mapToModel: true
  });
```

I am mapping the query result into the model `Link` with `mapToModel: true`. It works well but when I try to get some data from a joined table and map that into an object in model it doesn't convert into array.

For example I am trying to get domains like  `domains.id as 'domain.id', domains.host as 'domain.host',` This is how I saw sequlize does the query for eager loaded data.

But when I get the result object the I don't get a nested domain object property.

```
// desired link object
{
   id: 3,
   name: 'My test link',
   domain: {
      id: 23,
      host: 'example.com'
   }
}
```

instead what I get is

```
// current link object
{
   id: 3,
   name: 'My test link',
   'domain.id': 23,
   'domain.host': 'example.com'
}
```

So nested objects aren't mapping correctly.

### UPDATE

I have found [`nest` options in `query()`](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-method-query) documentation but setting `nest: true` doesn't seems to have any effect.

**Changed Query**

```
  const links = await sequelize.query(query.trim(), { 
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    model: Link,
    mapToModel: true,
    nest: true, // doesn't have any effect
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

For me `nest` worked only in conjunction with `raw`:

```
  const links = await sequelize.query(query.trim(), { 
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    model: Link,
    mapToModel: true,
    nest: true,
    raw: true // Without this `nest` hasn't effect, IDK why
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. The problem was this question was when I set it as raw I loose all methods associated with the model.

Answer (score 5):

I have run into the same problem. My solution was:

```js
return sequelize.query(/* query */, {
    nest: true,
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```

As you see, you should not set *mapToModel* prop, just *nest* and *type*.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `dottie` yourself, which is what `nest: true` is supposed to be doing (https://github.com/mickhansen/dottie.js):

```
import dottie from 'dottie';
// ...
const formattedLinks = links.map(l => dottie.transform(l.toJSON()))
```

Comment: Yes, tried it already but with dottie I loose all method associated with model

Answer (score 1):

It seems that raw queries with `nest:true` doesn't works with `mapToModel`. So the only way I found is to include `nest:true`, map with `Link.build(link)` and `{ include: Domain}` option:

```
  const query = `SELECT 
    links.name, links.type, links.code, links.originalUrl,
    domains.id as 'domain.id', domains.host as 'domain.host',

    count(
      CASE WHEN hits.datetime > "${past}" AND hits.datetime <= "${now}" = true then 1 END
    ) as hitCount 

    FROM links

    LEFT JOIN hits ON links.id = hits.linkId
    LEFT JOIN domains ON links.domainId = domains.id

    WHERE links.userId = ${req.user.id}

    GROUP BY links.id, hits.linkId

    ORDER BY hitCount DESC

    LIMIT 5`;

  const links = (await sequelize.query(query.trim(), { 
    nest: true,
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
  }));
  links.map((link) => Link.build(link, {include: Domain}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the Link model has one domain with association so you will need to pass 
`include: <domain model>` to map to domain model.

have a look at this : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1830